# Doubt regarding proof of denstity of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

A version of the proof that $\mathbb{Q}$ is everywhere dense in $\mathbb{R}$ (the one in "Stephen Abbott: understanding analysis") goes like this: Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a<b$. For simplicity assume $a\ge0$ ($a<0$ will be proved later). A rational number is a quotient of two integers so we must produce $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that:$$a<m/n<b.....(1)$$ Then we choose $n$ so that $$1/n<b-a.....(2)$$ (existence of $n$ guaranteed by A.P. (Archimedean property)).Multiplying $(1)$ by $n$ gives $na<m<nb$. We now choose $m$ to be the smallest natural number greater than $na$ i.e$$m-1\le^{(3)}na<^{(4)}m$$$(4)$ directly gives $a<m/n$ so half the work is done. $(2)$ can be written as $a<b-1/n$. From $(3)$: $$m\le na+1$$ $$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad<n(b-1/n)+1$$ $$=nb$$ $$\therefore m<nb\quad\implies m/n<b$$ The case in which $a<0$ can be proved without much work by converting it into the above case.**QUESTION:** I fail to understand why we have to take seperate cases for $a\ge 0$ & $a<0$. Assuming the problem is in $(3)$ & $(4)$, cant we just take $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ so that $(3)$ & $(4)$ are possible for -ve $a$ too ? I know $(4)$ requires the A.P. which is usually proved for $\mathbb{N}$ but isnt it obvious it holds for $\mathbb{Z}$ too ? Is there any other step which requires $a$ to be +ve or zero ?

Comment: See this [note](http://www.web.pdx.edu/~slarsen/MyMathDeptSite/webpage/311Page/Density%20of%20Q%20Proof.pdf) for a slightly different proof.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "smallest natural grater than.." (before (3) and (4))? Probably they have proved before that there exists a "smalles natural number in a nonempty set of natural numbers".

Comment: Clearly $m=na+1$, right? So there is no need to be concerned with existence of such $m$ unless we are down to the level of Peano's Axioms or something similar ...

Comment: @PeterFranek: The OP writes "no" meaning "number" which is quite distracting, I must admit ...

Comment: Ok, I see :-) However, $m=na+1$ doesn't hold in general, only for rational $a$. So, you need to have some argument to show that $m$ exists. I haven't read the book but a standard argument is that every nonempty set of natural numbers has a minimum.

Comment: @PeterFranek: Thanks! I did not think too deeply about it, I can see now :) BTW you are most certainly right about applying the smallest element of a non-empty set of natural numbers. And that does not extend directly without modification to $\mathbb Z$ since it is not bounded from below!

Comment: @String could you please explain why $m$ has to be equal to $na+1$ ?

Comment: @user134426: As I discussed with Peter Franek above, I was mistaken. Somehow $a$ had turned into an integer in my head. Then Peter Franek reminded me to "keep it real" ;)

Comment: @PeterFranek alhough Mr. Abbott doesnt establish that standard argument it does seem that it is the reason he confines $m$ to $\mathbb{N}$ and it definitely does make sense to me

Comment: @PeterFranek however for arguments sake the existence of $m\in \mathbb{Z}$ is also guaranteed as every set of  integers bounded below (in this case by $na$ )also has a minimum right ?

Comment: @user134426 yes, it can also be done directly for all integers, but something must be said; it can be 10 additional characters or maybe 20, no more :)

Comment: @PeterFranek alright so both methods approximately contain the same amount of matter. So I guess this version is justified and my doubt is cleared . Thank you peter franek :)